# Preview: reorder pages in pdf increased file size?

Tags: pdf, preview

I have scanned 58 pages into a PDF. The file size of this orginal pdf was 8 MB. Unfortunately the page order was a little messed up when I scanned so I used Preview to reordered some of the pages by simply dragging the pages around in the thumbnails bar. After doing this and saving the pdf the size had increased to 23 MB! What happened? And how do I reduce the file size?

I tried the reduce file size quarts filter but it reduced the resolution which made the pdf unusable.

I see no reason for the file size to increase from just reordering existing pages, is there?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it has to do, in my case, with embedding Types. 
after combinig them with preview or (I use a lot of chapters) the free tool PDF Merger Free (or in your case, reordering), it seems they swallow the whole fontbiblio (well, guess not, only feels like), so I drop them on the app PdfCompress (https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8823/pdfcompress), in which preferences I choosed, without touching the compression Size (just in the middle), as fonts base 14, or none (this is risky, don't do it without checking your whole Dok afterward, makes funny things if the fonts aren't standard).
Hope this helps...

Comment: Your situation is different from mine. Since I scanned my pages there are no fonts embedded, just image data.